# How to handle JmsChannelFactoryBean errors, is there a possibility of custom error channel usage?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have following configuration for creation of two channels (by using the JmsChannelFactoryBean):

```
@Bean
public JmsChannelFactoryBean jmsChannel(ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory) {
    JmsChannelFactoryBean fb = new JmsChannelFactoryBean(true);
    fb.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
    fb.setDestinationName("something.queue");
    fb.setErrorHandler(t -> log.error("something went wrong on jms channel", t));
    return fb;
}

@Bean
public JmsChannelFactoryBean jmsChannelDLQ(ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory) {
    JmsChannelFactoryBean fb = new JmsChannelFactoryBean(true);
    fb.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
    fb.setDestinationName("something.queue.DLQ");
    fb.setErrorHandler(t -> log.error("something went wrong on jms channel", t));
    return fb;
}
```

The something.queue is configured to put the dead letter on something.queue.DLQ. Im using mostly Java DSL to configure the app, and if possible - would like to keep this.

Case is: the message is taken from jmsChannel put to sftp outbound gateway, if there is a problem on sending the file, the message is put back into the jmsChannel as not delivered. After some retries it is designed as poisonus, and put to something.queue.DLQ.

1. Is it possbile to have the info on error channel when that happens?
2. What is best practice to handle errors when using JMS backed message channels?

**EDIT 2**

The integration flow is defined as:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(filesToProcessChannel).handle(outboundGateway)
```

Where  filesToProcessChannel is the JMS backed channel and outbound gateway is defined as:

```
@Bean
public SftpOutboundGateway outboundGateway(SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate) {
    SftpOutboundGateway gateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpRemoteFileTemplate, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.PUT.getCommand(), EXPRESSION_PAYLOAD);
    ArrayList<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<>();
    adviceChain.add(errorHandlingAdvice());
    gateway.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    return gateway;
}
```

Im trying to grab exception using advice:

```
@Bean
public Advice errorHandlingAdvice() {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(1);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    advice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(filesToProcessErrorChannel));
    return advice;
}
```

Is this the right way?

**EDIT 3**

There is certanly something wrong with SFTPOutboundGateway and advices (or with me :/):
I used the folowing advice from the spring integration reference:

```
@Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
    advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString(
            "payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow success() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow failure() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
}
```

And when I use :

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(filesToProcessChannel)
            .handle((GenericHandler<File>) (payload, headers) -> {
                if (payload.equals("x")) {
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("some failure");
                }
            }, spec -> spec.advice(expressionAdvice()))
```

It gets called, and i get error message printed out (and that is expected), but when I try to use:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(filesToProcessChannel)
            .handle(outboundGateway, spec -> spec.advice(expressionAdvice()))
```

The advice is not called, and the error message is put back to JMS.

The app is using Spring Boot v2.0.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.4.RELEASE.

**EDIT 4**

I managed to resolve the advice issue using following configuration, still don't understand why the handler spec will not work:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow files(SftpOutboundGateway outboundGateway,
                      ...
) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(filesToProcessChannel)
            .handle(outboundGateway)
            ...
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public SftpOutboundGateway outboundGateway(SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate) {
    SftpOutboundGateway gateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpRemoteFileTemplate, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.PUT.getCommand(), EXPRESSION_PAYLOAD);
    ArrayList<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<>();
    adviceChain.add(expressionAdvice());
    gateway.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    return gateway;
}


@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
    advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString(
            "payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow success() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow failure() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the movement to the DLQ is performed by the broker, the application has no mechanism to log the situation - it is not even aware that it happened.

You would have to catch the exceptions yourself and publish the message the the DLQ yourself, after some number of attempts (`JMSXDeliveryCount` header), instead of using the broker policy.

**EDIT**

Add an `Advice` to the `.handle()` step.

```
.handle(outboundGateway, e -> e.advice(myAdvice))
```

Where `myAdvice` implements `MethodInterceptor`.

In the `invoke` method, after a failure, you can check the delivery count header and, if it exceeds your threshold, publish the message to the DLQ (e.g. send it to another channel that has a JMS outbound adapter subscribed) and log the error; if the threshold has not been exceeded, simply return the result of the `invocation.proceed()` (or rethrow the exception).

That way, you control publishing to the DLQ rather than having the broker do it. You can also add more information, such as the exception, to headers.

**EDIT2**

You need something like this

```
public class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel toJms;

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
        catch Exception(e) {
            Message<?> message = (Message<?>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            Integer redeliveries = messasge.getHeader("JMXRedeliveryCount", Integer.class);
            if (redeliveries != null && redeliveries > 3) {
                this.toJms.send(message); // maybe rebuild with additional headers about the error
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(it should be close, but I haven't tested it). It assumes your broker populates that header.

Comment: I added the idea of configuration to my previous post.

Comment: I tried something simple like:
IntegrationFlows.from(filesToProcessChannel)
                .handle(outboundGateway, e -> e.advice((MethodInterceptor) invocation -> {
                    Object proceed = invocation.proceed();
                    return proceed;
                }))

I put a breakpoint on the Object proceed = invocation.proceed(); but it will not stop. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question instead and add a comment to say you have done so. See my second edit.

Comment: Your first answer was right, the using advice to work around - should work. I did the test with GenericHandler -> advice working as expected, test with gateway -> not working, the advice is not getting caled, dont know the reason.

I added the code that is working, and the one that is not.

And sorry for code in comment, was in a bit of hurry to respond.

Comment: Your ` .handle(outboundGateway, spec -> spec.advice(expressionAdvice()))` will work if you don't declare `outboundGateway()` as a `@Bean`. Just because you can't mutate a bean state after its initialization. Or otherwise it would be better as you finally do - initialize bean and use it in DSL only as a reference. There is an `Sftp.outboundGateway()`  factory though instead.